# Meaning of the time idleing in in high intensive loads | chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was wondering what the ratio of time used for scripting etc vs the time idleing etc. tells me:

I noticed when i Have bad performance on the page / low fps in a 3D-scene the time "idleing" increases. What does that mean? Shoudln't the GPU time be 100% ?

5000 objects:

[CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkUOS.png)
[GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DS7K.png)

500 objects

[CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOEm9.png)
[GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6eKt.png)

In the scene with 5000 objects i get low fps but also more idleing time?

Comment: Why should it be 100%? The complete process is 5656ms long and the cpu is working 100% of that time. GPU already finished after 1949ms and then waited for cpu to complete. Seems fine...

Comment: I added 2 more picutres. The scene with 500 objects takes more CPU and GPU time than the scene with 5000.